# Returning a single minimum date value from a key across multiple objects with jq

Tags: jq

I've got a set of objects as below, and I'm trying to obtain just a single date value from across all of them.

The desired output is:

`"2014-12-16T08:59:08.000+0100"`

The data set is:

```
[
  {
    "key": "AB-12345",
    "type": "Fault",
    "typeid": "19",
    "status": "Open",
    "summary": "I'm a big bad fault",
    "closedDate": null,
    "flag": null
  },
  {
    "key": "AB-12346",
    "type": "Bug",
    "typeid": "19",
    "status": "Open",
    "summary": "I'm a big bad bug",
    "closedDate": "2014-12-16T08:59:08.000+0100",
    "flag": null
  },
  {
    "key": "AB-12347",
    "type": "Feature",
    "typeid": "19",
    "status": "Open",
    "summary": "I'm a big bad feature",
    "closedDate": "2014-12-17T08:27:07.000+0100",
    "flag": null
  }
 ]
```

I've managed to get as far as using:

`.[] | {"closedDate": .closedDate} | select(.closedDate > 0)`

Which will get me:

```
{
  "closedDate": "2014-12-16T08:59:08.000+0100"
}
{
  "closedDate": "2014-12-17T08:27:07.000+0100"
}
```

but I can't figure out a way of using `select`, `max_by` or `min_by` to achieve this.

I'm on jq 1.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map each entry to the `closedDate` filtering out non-values, then get the minimum value.

```
map(.closedDate | values) | min
```

Comment: assuming the values are all on the same side of GMT; e.g. `2014-12-17T08:27:07.000-0200` will break it

Comment: @HansZ. Considering the data is coming from the same source, it would be unlikely that the data isn't normalized. If it wasn't, it should be but is not our concern.

Comment: I'm just adding for completeness. The source may have gathered this data from different locations without normalizing it, then it would be a concern. I guess I'm saying `jq` should have support for handling timestamps.

Comment: @HansZ. A feature for handling timestamps doesn't exist although I saw a feature request somewhere on jq github for something similar. As to the source, the timestamps are all from the same place, so no normalisation is necessary.